# Chaining promises with promise all results in unexpected execution order

Tags: javascript, promise

Why does the following code print `baz, done` before `1, 2, 3`?

```js
const bar = () => Promise.resolve([1, 2, 3]);
const cat = e => {
  console.log(e);
  return Promise.resolve(e);
};
const foo = () =>
  bar()
    .then(arr => Promise.all(arr.map(e => cat(e))))
    .then(console.log("baz"));

foo().then(console.log("done"));
```

Comment: You probably mean : `foo().then(() => console.log("done"));`

Comment: @Axnyff and `.then(() => console.log("baz"));`

Comment: It doesn't. When I run it it prints "baz", "done", then "1", "2", "3".

Comment: Your example doesn't produce the stated behavior (_"...print baz and done after 1, 2, 3"_), so please edit it to create a real [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are executing console.log() immediately instead of passing it to callback function in .then(). This will do it:

```js
const bar = () => Promise.resolve([1, 2, 3]);

const cat = e => {
  console.log(e);
  return Promise.resolve(e);
};

const foo = () =>
  bar()
    .then(arr => Promise.all(arr.map(e => cat(e))))
    .then(() => console.log("baz"));
    
foo().then(() => console.log("done"));
```

Comment: @user2133814 How is this the answer? _"You are executing console.log() immediately"_ (`baz` and `done` would be logged before `[1,2,3]` which it does in TOs snippet) vs _"...print baz and done **after** 1, 2, 3?"_ (which would only be the case when TO already used the code from this answer)

Comment: @Andreas running the snippet above produces the output I want.  Running the snippet I posted in the question produces something different which is not what I want.  The explanation of not passing it to the callback answers the "why".  Isn't that the definition of good answer?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @user2133814 Your question didn't make much sense because the text didn't match the output of the code. Only after your last edit the text matches the code. And now this answer is really an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to embed the `console.log` into arrow functions so their execution is properly deferred:

```js
const bar = () => Promise.resolve([1, 2, 3]);
const cat = e => {
  console.log(e);
  return Promise.resolve(e);
};
const foo = () =>
  bar()
    .then(arr => Promise.all(arr.map(e => cat(e))))
    .then(() => console.log("baz"));

foo().then(() => console.log("done"));
```